# Who is this Lawrence Bonavia?

Tags: poetry, maltese-language, john-p-portelli

One of John P. Portelli's Maltese poems is entitled "To Fr. Lawrence Bonavia" ("Lil Fr. Lawrence Bonavia" in Maltese): it's number 52 in his poetry book [available from his website](http://john-peter-portelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Bejn-Zewg-Dinjiet-Text-Copy.pdf) (pp. 107-110 in the linked PDF). The opening stanza is:

> As a Father we salute you
> gentle friar here among us,
> much faith, much zeal you’ve shown us
> like the good shepherd cared about us.

The poem later mentions "in Fingal you found sweet rest" and "to live as a Franciscan / in a Province far away"; it's all very Christian and religious in theme and wording. But **who is this Lawrence Bonavia?**

I searched online for Lawrence Bonavia and found [one at the University of Malta](https://www.um.edu.mt/profile/lawrencebonavia) and [one working for the Maltese government](https://deputyprimeminister.gov.mt/en/Pages/Contact-Details.aspx) as well as a [Londoner on Twitter](https://twitter.com/lolbonavia) by that name. Perhaps the name [Bonavia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonavia) is a common one in Malta. But is there a specific real person that Portelli's poem was addressed or dedicated to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He was the chaplain aboard the Vulcania, which carried the second group of Maltese migrants to Canada in 1948.

According to [Maltamigration.com](https://maltamigration.com/history/valve/chapter3f.html):

> The chaplain on board was Fr Lawrence Bonavia who was later on to be appointed parish priest of the Maltese church of St Paul in Toronto.

I found this link by searching for the name Bonavia along with 'Fingal' and 'St Paul' as mentioned in the 3rd and 6th verses.

Comment: Ah, that fits. Portelli is himself a Maltese migrant in Canada, so it makes sense that he'd know this Lawrence Bonavia rather than the others I found on the internet.